# How to get an element in each row from a complete array in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm inserting a group of elements in database, I'm trying to get one element for each row but I'm obtaining all elements in one row and every row from the database is repeated like this

[image]

I would like to get one element for row in the column.. I'm using this query

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();

    foreach ($data as $val) { 
    DB::table('clientes_view')->insert(['resultado' => $data]);
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are inserting the `$data` instead of `$val`,

You can get all `$data`, and **insert them at once**, like this:

```php
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif AS resultado')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();
// If you are using Eloquent, you can just use ->toarray();
// For query builder, you need to change stdClass to array, so I use json_decode()
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data, true), true);

DB::table('clientes_view')->insert($data);
```

---

`updateOrInsert` only supports **one record**, so if you want to use this method:

```php
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select('incidencias.rif AS resultado')
   ->distinct()
   ->get();
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data, true), true);
forEach($data as $val) {
    DB::table('clientes_view')->updateOrInsert($val, $val);
}
```

Comment: Im getting this error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: I think that I have to invoke the class because I got this error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ATC\json_ecode() Which class do I have to invoke?

Comment: @LaravelOscar sorry, that's my mistake, It's `json_encode()`...

Comment: thanks a lot!! Hey! I would like to updateOrInsert instead of insert... It's the same?

Comment: @LaravelOscar u'r welcome, `updateOrInsert` only support to one record, if you want to use this method, you need to loop it, like `foreach ($data as $val) { Model::updateOrInsert($val, $val)`

Comment: could you put and updateOrInsert in your answer instead of an insert please?

Comment: @LaravelOscar I have post it.